# BrowserStack + Protractor getting the name of the tests to show up as session ID

Tags: protractor, browserstack

I know that you could use browserstack before protractor 3.0 but they have added official support in 3.0 . I haven't been able to try that out yet so maybe that's the answer to my question? Currently don't have the ability to upgrade so if that's my answer then I will go through the proper channels to make that happen.

The problem I'm having with browser stack is that it names all the sessions random hashes. So I may have a suite of tests and I have no way to tell which session is which test. You can manually change the capabilities.name but then everything will have that name.

I know when I use saucelabs it will name everything after the name of the test file. so for example it will be sometest.js . I don't know if this is something protractor is doing or some node-module we're using that is doing the work behind the scenes and I don't know?

I just want to know how I can run my suite that runs all my smoketests and names each browserstack session after the actual name of the tests in the suite.

### here is an example of what things look like on **browserstack**. I did manually set the capabilities.name to mytest for a few sessions.

[image]

### here is how they look with **sauce labs**

[image]

Also here is my package.json file in case any of these modules might be making saucelabs name the jobs after the test file name

```
{
  "name": "protractor",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Protractor protype",
  "main": "Gruntfile.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt-sauce-tunnel": "^0.2.1",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.1.1",
    "lodash": "^3.2.0",
    "protractor": "2.5.1",
    "require-all": "2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chalk": "^1.1.1",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-env": "^0.4.2",
    "grunt-protractor-runner": "3.0.0",
    "grunt-sauce-connect-launcher": "^0.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.2.3",
    "request-promise": "^1.0.2",
    "selenium-webdriver": "2.48.2",
    "xlsx-json": "^0.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "install": "node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git:user/rwolfe/protractor"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't know if this was due to upgrading to protractor 3.0 or not but apparently in the conf.js I saw that for sauce labs we were setting

```
exports.config.capabilities.name = " ";
```

and when I did that for browserstack now the names of the test show up how I would expect as below.

[image]